# UWP подключение к SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp

Есть приложение `WPF`, которое работает с базой данных `SQL`. В `App.xaml` указана строка подключения к тестовой БД. Планируется перетащить данное приложение на `UWP`. Скопировав данную строку подключения испытываю сложность подключения к тестовой БД.
Строка подключения к тестовой БД выглядит следующим образом:

```
SqlConnection("Data Source=204-1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
```

Как я уже говорил, в `WPF` приложении строка работает.
При копировании данной строки подключения в `UWP` появляются следующие ошибки:

```
Exception: Failed to generate SSPI context.
ErrorCode=NoCredentials
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext(SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, Byte[] receivedBuff, Byte[]& sendBuff, Byte[] serverName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext(Byte[] receivedBuff, UInt32 receivedLength, Byte[]& sendBuff, UInt32& sendLength, Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData(Byte[] receivedBuff, UInt32 receivedLength, Byte[]& sendBuff, UInt32& sendLength)
```

Данная ошибка возникает при следующих строках:

- `Data Source=204-1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;`
- `Data Source=204-1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=DbAdmin;`
- `Data Source=204-1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True`

Какую строку необходимо использовать для подключения к `SQL Server` в приложениях `UWP`?
Так же, буду рад узнать, в чём принципиальная разница между подключением к `SQL Server` в приложениях `WPF` и `UWP`?

Comment: То есть, я вижу, что VS выдаёт исключение в связи с неправильными учётными данными. Но какие бы учётные данные я не передал строке, они не работают. Сама тестовая БД установлена на ВМ и не требует пароля.

Comment: [Это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases) смотрели?

Comment: @ixSci да, это была первая ссылка у всех поисковых систем и запросов в стиле UWP SQL.

Comment: А [это](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24336)?

Comment: @ixSci если быть ещё точнее, то ответ находится по этой ссылке https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22890#issuecomment-333305084. Вынесите ваш комментарии в ответ и я закрою его. Благодарю.

Comment: Лучше напишите ответ сами, с некоторыми подробностями. Так будет лучше; я просто нашёл ссылку, я в проблеме не разбираюсь.

Comment: @ixSci стыдно признаться, но я и в первой ссылке пропустил момент с включением дополнительной возможности и сразу отправился читать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подвела собственная невнимательность. В статье [Майкрософт](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases) указывается информация, что если используется проверка на уровне ОС, то в **.appxmanifest** в разделе **Возможности** нужно включить "**Корпоративная проверка подлинности**".